# How can I extract out the value of X, Y, Z in a list of dataset in Python?

Tags: python

I was given a set of dataset as show below,

How can I extracted out the value of X, Y, Z of each series in Python?

I actually later need to calculate the standard deviation of each series. (x, y, z standard deviation)

```
{'deviceTimestamp': 166230, 'x': 3.5538, 'y': -9.7006, 'z': 3.3077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166250, 'x': -1.4629, 'y': -7.0692, 'z': 2.2308}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166260, 'x': -6.7571, 'y': -5.0299, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166280, 'x': -5.0319, 'y': -6.5896, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166300, 'x': -0.21122, 'y': -8.9002, 'z': 2.5}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166320, 'x': 6.3477, 'y': -9.3142, 'z': 4.5385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166340, 'x': 10.904, 'y': -9.9498, 'z': 5.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166360, 'x': 9.5501, 'y': -8.5014, 'z': 5.6923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166380, 'x': 7.7312, 'y': -8.5973, 'z': 5.6154}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166400, 'x': 8.9783, 'y': -10.132, 'z': 4.7692}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166420, 'x': 9.8307, 'y': -11.159, 'z': 5.0385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166440, 'x': 7.7934, 'y': -10.556, 'z': 5.8077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166460, 'x': 5.8261, 'y': -10.259, 'z': 2.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166480, 'x': 4.4837, 'y': -10.092, 'z': 1.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166500, 'x': 5.5556, 'y': -11.08, 'z': 1.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166520, 'x': 8.4009, 'y': -12.06, 'z': 1.0}
```

Comment: If you need just values - `[list(d.values())[1:] for d in dataset]` *(python 3.6+)*

Comment: mention how do you want it to store these after extraction.

Comment: @VishalSingh I actually want to calculate the standard deviation after extract the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to construct a list with x, y, z.

```
data = [
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166230, 'x': 3.5538, 'y': -9.7006, 'z': 3.3077}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166250, 'x': -1.4629, 'y': -7.0692, 'z': 2.2308}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166260, 'x': -6.7571, 'y': -5.0299, 'z': -0.076923}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166280, 'x': -5.0319, 'y': -6.5896, 'z': -0.076923}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166300, 'x': -0.21122, 'y': -8.9002, 'z': 2.5}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166320, 'x': 6.3477, 'y': -9.3142, 'z': 4.5385}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166340, 'x': 10.904, 'y': -9.9498, 'z': 5.6538}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166360, 'x': 9.5501, 'y': -8.5014, 'z': 5.6923},
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166380, 'x': 7.7312, 'y': -8.5973, 'z': 5.6154}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166400, 'x': 8.9783, 'y': -10.132, 'z': 4.7692}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166420, 'x': 9.8307, 'y': -11.159, 'z': 5.0385}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166440, 'x': 7.7934, 'y': -10.556, 'z': 5.8077}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166460, 'x': 5.8261, 'y': -10.259, 'z': 2.8462}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166480, 'x': 4.4837, 'y': -10.092, 'z': 1.6538}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166500, 'x': 5.5556, 'y': -11.08, 'z': 1.8462}, 
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166520, 'x': 8.4009, 'y': -12.06, 'z': 1.0}
]

coordinates = [[d['x'], d['y'], d['z']] for d in data]
```

Then the `coordinates` list is:

```
[[3.5538, -9.7006, 3.3077],
 [-1.4629, -7.0692, 2.2308],
 [-6.7571, -5.0299, -0.076923],
 [-5.0319, -6.5896, -0.076923],
 [-0.21122, -8.9002, 2.5],
 [6.3477, -9.3142, 4.5385],
 [10.904, -9.9498, 5.6538],
 [9.5501, -8.5014, 5.6923],
 [7.7312, -8.5973, 5.6154],
 [8.9783, -10.132, 4.7692],
 [9.8307, -11.159, 5.0385],
 [7.7934, -10.556, 5.8077],
 [5.8261, -10.259, 2.8462],
 [4.4837, -10.092, 1.6538],
 [5.5556, -11.08, 1.8462],
 [8.4009, -12.06, 1.0]]
```

---

To get the standard deviation, you can use `numpy` or write your own function.

```
import numpy as np

# Population standard deviation per coordinate.
np.std(coordinates, axis=1)
# array([6.19099304, 3.82337866, 2.83117498, 2.77675246, 4.86271126,
#        6.99575755, 8.85637189, 7.76173229, 7.25026715, 8.19868452,
#        8.98079242, 8.22201761, 6.98694428, 6.31068919, 7.1304471 ,
#        8.45895548])
```

Here is a similar function using the standard library.

```
import math

def stdev(values):
    mean = sum(values) / len(values)
    numerator = sum((x - mean) ** 2 for x in values)
    denominator = len(values)
    return math.sqrt(numerator / denominator)

[stdev(c) for c in coordinates]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. It is possible to get the standard deviation of each elements, instead of all x? for example: `[[3.5538, -9.7006, 3.3077] --> Standard deviation`

Comment: Sure, see my exits. You can use the `axis` parameter in `numpy.std`. If this answered your question, please click the green check mark to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use the keys in a comprehension as others have show. However, I like the functional style and succinctness of [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) when there are multiple keys. You can create a list or use `map` (or both). For example:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [{'deviceTimestamp': 166230, 'x': 3.5538, 'y': -9.7006, 'z': 3.3077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166250, 'x': -1.4629, 'y': -7.0692, 'z': 2.2308}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166260, 'x': -6.7571, 'y': -5.0299, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166280, 'x': -5.0319, 'y': -6.5896, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166300, 'x': -0.21122, 'y': -8.9002, 'z': 2.5}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166320, 'x': 6.3477, 'y': -9.3142, 'z': 4.5385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166340, 'x': 10.904, 'y': -9.9498, 'z': 5.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166360, 'x': 9.5501, 'y': -8.5014, 'z': 5.6923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166380, 'x': 7.7312, 'y': -8.5973, 'z': 5.6154}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166400, 'x': 8.9783, 'y': -10.132, 'z': 4.7692}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166420, 'x': 9.8307, 'y': -11.159, 'z': 5.0385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166440, 'x': 7.7934, 'y': -10.556, 'z': 5.8077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166460, 'x': 5.8261, 'y': -10.259, 'z': 2.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166480, 'x': 4.4837, 'y': -10.092, 'z': 1.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166500, 'x': 5.5556, 'y': -11.08, 'z': 1.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166520, 'x': 8.4009, 'y': -12.06, 'z': 1.0}]

# coords is an iterator
coord = map(itemgetter('x','y','z'), data)

# you can make a list if you want
list(coord)

# or loop over the values without making a list:
coord = map(itemgetter('x','y','z'), data)  
for x, y, z in coord:
    print(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using python 3

```py
data = {'deviceTimestamp': 166230, 'x': 3.5538, 'y': -9.7006, 'z': 3.3077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166250, 'x': -1.4629, 'y': -7.0692, 'z': 2.2308}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166260, 'x': -6.7571, 'y': -5.0299, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166280, 'x': -5.0319, 'y': -6.5896, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166300, 'x': -0.21122, 'y': -8.9002, 'z': 2.5}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166320, 'x': 6.3477, 'y': -9.3142, 'z': 4.5385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166340, 'x': 10.904, 'y': -9.9498, 'z': 5.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166360, 'x': 9.5501, 'y': -8.5014, 'z': 5.6923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166380, 'x': 7.7312, 'y': -8.5973, 'z': 5.6154}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166400, 'x': 8.9783, 'y': -10.132, 'z': 4.7692}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166420, 'x': 9.8307, 'y': -11.159, 'z': 5.0385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166440, 'x': 7.7934, 'y': -10.556, 'z': 5.8077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166460, 'x': 5.8261, 'y': -10.259, 'z': 2.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166480, 'x': 4.4837, 'y': -10.092, 'z': 1.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166500, 'x': 5.5556, 'y': -11.08, 'z': 1.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166520, 'x': 8.4009, 'y': -12.06, 'z': 1.0}

for item in data:
    print(item[x])
    print(item[y])
    print(item[z])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
list_ = [{'deviceTimestamp': 166230, 'x': 3.5538, 'y': -9.7006, 'z': 3.3077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166250, 'x': -1.4629, 'y': -7.0692, 'z': 2.2308}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166260, 'x': -6.7571, 'y': -5.0299, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166280, 'x': -5.0319, 'y': -6.5896, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166300, 'x': -0.21122, 'y': -8.9002, 'z': 2.5}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166320, 'x': 6.3477, 'y': -9.3142, 'z': 4.5385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166340, 'x': 10.904, 'y': -9.9498, 'z': 5.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166360, 'x': 9.5501, 'y': -8.5014, 'z': 5.6923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166380, 'x': 7.7312, 'y': -8.5973, 'z': 5.6154}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166400, 'x': 8.9783, 'y': -10.132, 'z': 4.7692}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166420, 'x': 9.8307, 'y': -11.159, 'z': 5.0385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166440, 'x': 7.7934, 'y': -10.556, 'z': 5.8077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166460, 'x': 5.8261, 'y': -10.259, 'z': 2.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166480, 'x': 4.4837, 'y': -10.092, 'z': 1.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166500, 'x': 5.5556, 'y': -11.08, 'z': 1.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166520, 'x': 8.4009, 'y': -12.06, 'z': 1.0}]

out = []
for dict_ in list_:
    out.append([dict_['x'], dict_['y'], dict_['z']])

print(out)

print('standard deviation row-wise:', np.std(out, axis = 1))
```

output:

```
[[3.5538, -9.7006, 3.3077], 
[-1.4629, -7.0692, 2.2308], 
[-6.7571, -5.0299, -0.076923], 
[-5.0319, -6.5896, -0.076923], 
[-0.21122, -8.9002, 2.5], 
[6.3477, -9.3142, 4.5385], 
[10.904, -9.9498, 5.6538], 
[9.5501, -8.5014, 5.6923], 
[7.7312, -8.5973, 5.6154], 
[8.9783, -10.132, 4.7692], 
[9.8307, -11.159, 5.0385], 
[7.7934, -10.556, 5.8077], 
[5.8261, -10.259, 2.8462], 
[4.4837, -10.092, 1.6538], 
[5.5556, -11.08, 1.8462], 
[8.4009, -12.06, 1.0]]

standard deviation row-wise: 
[6.19099304 3.82337866 2.83117498 2.77675246 4.86271126 6.99575755
 8.85637189 7.76173229 7.25026715 8.19868452 8.98079242 8.22201761
 6.98694428 6.31068919 7.1304471  8.45895548]
```

Comment: Thanks, it is correct. But I want for each element, instead of combine all x, y, z

Comment: Sreenias, yes, thanks. How about finding the standard deviation of each elements?

Comment: @Alan Yep added

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset = [
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166230, 'x': 3.5538, 'y': -9.7006, 'z': 3.3077},
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166250, 'x': -1.4629, 'y': -7.0692, 'z': 2.2308}
    {'deviceTimestamp': 166260, 'x': -6.7571, 'y': -5.0299, 'z': -0.076923},
]

for data in dataset:
    print(data['x'], data['y'], data['z'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`[_['x'] for _ in dataset]`

`[_['y'] for _ in dataset]`

`[_['z'] for _ in dataset]`

Comment: Underscore commonly used for indicating variable you won't work with in future, it's not good to use it for naming regular variables, use any letter from latin alphabet instead.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the stdev of each of `'x'`, `'y'` and `'z'` you can use [stdev](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) from the Python statistics package:

```
>>> data_set
({'deviceTimestamp': 166230, 'x': 3.5538, 'y': -9.7006, 'z': 3.3077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166250, 'x': -1.4629, 'y': -7.0692, 'z': 2.2308}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166260, 'x': -6.7571, 'y': -5.0299, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166280, 'x': -5.0319, 'y': -6.5896, 'z': -0.076923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166300, 'x': -0.21122, 'y': -8.9002, 'z': 2.5}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166320, 'x': 6.3477, 'y': -9.3142, 'z': 4.5385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166340, 'x': 10.904, 'y': -9.9498, 'z': 5.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166360, 'x': 9.5501, 'y': -8.5014, 'z': 5.6923}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166380, 'x': 7.7312, 'y': -8.5973, 'z': 5.6154}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166400, 'x': 8.9783, 'y': -10.132, 'z': 4.7692}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166420, 'x': 9.8307, 'y': -11.159, 'z': 5.0385}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166440, 'x': 7.7934, 'y': -10.556, 'z': 5.8077}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166460, 'x': 5.8261, 'y': -10.259, 'z': 2.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166480, 'x': 4.4837, 'y': -10.092, 'z': 1.6538}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166500, 'x': 5.5556, 'y': -11.08, 'z': 1.8462}, {'deviceTimestamp': 166520, 'x': 8.4009, 'y': -12.06, 'z': 1.0})

from statistics import stdev 

std_dev={}
for k in 'xyz':
    std_dev[k]=stdev([x for d in data_set for x in  [v for kt,v in d.items() if kt==k]])

>>> std_dev
{'x': 5.3742701745097445, 'y': 1.834613985511212, 'z': 2.0740453969047343}
```